# How to allow user to upload attachments in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-sharing

In case of Android when I want to send or attach a document such as a pdf or doc from my application I can easily access all the files in the external storage and share or attach.

But since iOS follows a sandbox approach as well as there is no filesystem so it is not possible to attach or upload in same manner.

In my iOS application right now, I have implemented Open In functionality, wherein in the info.plist file I have specified that my application supports all types of documents so when the user opens any documents he gets an option to Open In my application, then I save that document in the

```
Documents/Incoming
```

folder in the application, now when my user clicks to add attachment then he can see the document to attach, since this is a long process I was looking for better ones.

I saw whatsApp allows uploading/sharing from iCloud apart from that what can I do to provide a similar behaviour as Android.

Comment: In android you can upload a document because you can invoke the file manager where you can check for documents. But in ios you do not have any file manager to view files.If you copy any pdf file into iphone by default it stores in ibooks app. You can not access the data from ibooks.You can upload documents through icloud.